# What permission is needed for using web sql in google chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-sql

I have created a simple HTML document that uses webSQL storage, it works perfectly when it is run in the Google Chrome browser. But when I try to load it as a Google extension the data is not stored in webSQL.

What permission is needed for using web sql in a google chrome extension?

Note: 
I tried "unlimitedStorage" permission, still it is not working properly.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the code on jsfiddle or jsbin? Also, do you call it from a background page?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring “browsingdata” permission, check details here

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData.html